# How to calculate the time to fetch records from Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a simple job with trigger=15 seconds, Source=Kafka and Sink=S3. Is it possible to find how much time did it take to download messages from Kafka? Or say if I had Sink=Console, it bring back data on the driver, is it possible to find how much time to download data from Kafka and how much time to bring it back to driver?

From driver I get these for query while writing to S3. Is it possible to understand how much time did it spend in downloading 99998 rows from Kafka out of triggerExecution = 44 seconds?

```
Streaming query made progress: {
  id : 1383g52b-8de4-4e95-a3s9-aea73qe3ea56,
  runId : 1206f5tc-t503-44r0-bc0c-26ce404w6724,
  name : null,
  timestamp : 2017-08-25T01:42:10.000Z,
  numInputRows : 99998,
  inputRowsPerSecond : 1666.6333333333334,
  processedRowsPerSecond : 2263.9860535669814,
  durationMs : {
    addBatch : 42845,
    getBatch : 3,
    getOffset : 68,
    queryPlanning : 6,
    triggerExecution : 44169,
    walCommit : 1245
  },
  stateOperators : [ ],
  sources : [ {
    description : KafkaSource[Subscribe[kafka_topic]],
    startOffset : {
      kafka_topic : {
        2 : 20119244,
        4 : 20123550,
        1 : 20124601,
        3 : 20113622,
        0 : 20114208
      }
    },
    endOffset : {
      kafka_topic : {
        2 : 20139245,
        4 : 20143531,
        1 : 20144592,
        3 : 20133663,
        0 : 20134192
      }
    },
    numInputRows : 99998,
    inputRowsPerSecond : 1666.6333333333334,
    processedRowsPerSecond : 2263.9860535669814
  } ],
  sink : {
    description : FileSink[s3://s3bucket]
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I worked around the problem by implementing a ForEachSink which doesn't do any real processing, that gave me pure time to download kafka events. ForeachSink: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/ForeachSink.scala

Answer (score 1):

You should find the answers to your questions by reviewing `StreamingQuery.lastProgress.durationMs`.

In the order of their calculation the following durations tell you:

- `getOffset` is the time to get the offsets from all the sources
- `getBatch` is the time to get the streaming Datasets (aka batches) from all the sources (one by one, sequentially).
- `addBatch` is the time to write the streaming Dataset to a sink

With that said...

> Is it possible to find how much time did it take to download messages from Kafka?

That's `addBatch` duration (since that's when the Dataset gets executed as an RDD on executors)

> Is it possible to understand how much time did it spend in downloading 99998 rows from Kafka out of triggerExecution = 44 seconds?

You'd have to sum `addBatch` durations from `StreamingQuery.recentProgress` array.

Comment: "addBatch is the time to write the streaming Dataset to a sink" -> so this time includes downloading the messages + writing them to temporary fs + uploading them to s3, how to separate out just the time to download from kafka?

Comment: Is there a doc explaining all fields of `StreamingQueryProgress`?

Comment: @Leon https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/progress.scala#L71-L94?

Comment: Could you please help to comment the other items of `durationMs`:  `queryPlanning`, `triggerExecution`, ,`walCommit`?

Comment: Would you mind if I asked you to ask another question so the answer(s) find their proper place? You may find some more information at https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-StreamingQueryProgress.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the reading from Kafka and the processing of the read records are pipelined, it is pretty hard to find the exact time taken to read.

And many times this is not important because processing is the bottleneck rather than reading from Kafka. So the real question is, why do you care about the exact Kafka read time?

Comment: I wanted to calculate avg latency to download from kafka vs that to upload to S3. I agree, because it's pipeline model it's hard to find exact time, I was just expecting that since there are distinct source and sinks, there might be a way to telling how much time each component in pipeline took.